# When i return one product with its images in morph relation it returns all the products

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have a problem when I make a route to get one product by it's `id`

```
Route::get('product/{product}', 'Api\ProductController@show');
```

and my `show` method looks like this:

```
    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return $product->with('images')->get();
    }
```

> it should return back to me only one product instead it returns all  the products

The morph relation in the `Product` model

```
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what masses it up is the use of `get()` that returns a collection of all the products that way.. Try this instead:

```
public function show(Product $product)
{
   $product->load('images');

   return $product;
}
```